# Why does Prettier break up my JSON object into multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, jsx, prettier

Prettier is great, but it breaks up my javascript object into multiple lines, like so:

```
<Text
    style={
        styles.chineseText
    }
>
    {
        this.state
            .housePayload
            .sitMountain
            .chinese
    }
</Text>
```

I'd like the result to be something along the lines of :

```
<Text
    style={
        styles.chineseText
    }
>
    { this.state.housePayload.sitMountain.chinese }
</Text>
```

How can I make this happen? My current config file is:

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: Did you try printWidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `printWidth` in the config. The default is `80` and you can specify any number that suits you. For e.g:

```
printWidth: 100
```

From the [Doc](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width)

> It is a way to say to Prettier roughly how long you’d like lines to
> be. Prettier will make both shorter and longer lines, but generally
> strive to meet the specified printWidth.

It's also important to note though:

> Don't try to use `printWidth` as if it was ESLint’s `max-len` – they’re
> not the same. `max-len` just says what the maximum allowed line length
> is, but not what the generally preferred length is – which is what
> `printWidth` specifies.